# Can I use jQuery with HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What browsers support HTML 5 / CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617200/what-browsers-support-html-5-css3)

I keep hearing about HTML5. If I start learning it and using it, will I have any browser compatibility issues?

I use jQuery considerably. Has it been upgraded to be compatible with HTML5? Basically, is it safe to use HTML5 now, or better to wait?

Comment: What do you mean by "use HTML5"?

Comment: @Pekka: agree on HTML5 browser compatibility, but it seems like the jQuery+HTML5 question hasn’t really been asked on SO yet.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 is a collection of different features that are each being adopted by the different browsers at different paces. So whether its worth using now depends on which feature you are interested in using and which browsers you need to support.

The question that Pekka linked to references a number of sites that will give you an idea of which features are supported in which browsers.

Also take a look at http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/ for more background.

**UPDATE**:
I don't see any reason not to use jQuery with HTML5 where appropriate. The JavaScript examples in http://pragprog.com/titles/bhh5/html5-and-css3 use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994578/will-jquery-ever-leverage-html5-technologies/2994591#2994591) claims that jQuery works fine with HTML5, but it doesn’t include (and I haven’t been able to find) any references in support.

jQuery should generally work fine with HTML5, as HTML5, as far as possible, is based on existing browser behaviour. Not sure if there would be any issues in older browsers though.

E.g. IE 6 doesn’t handle new HTML5 elements (like `<article>` and `<section>`) properly without some JavaScript help. One assumes jQuery plays nice with this, but I don’t actually know. See e.g. [jQuery, html5, append()/appendTo() and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191164/jquery-html5-append-appendto-and-ie) for a possible issue.

Answer (score 1):

jquery works the same in HTML5 documents as it does in HTML4.01 documents. There is no difference at all until jquery starts using HTML5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have issues with IE and old versions of FF, Safari, etc...

Comment: But, to be fair, since FF, Safari, etc (almost all but IE) have some sort of auto-update, there aren't very many old versions of them around.  IE is the main problem, and IE9 supports much of HTML5.

Comment: @andrewmu I think "much" is not the appropriate word here :) It supports less than 50% of HTML5 features. http://html5test.com/

Comment: @Šime yes! But the main thing that people think of as HTML5 (border-radius) is partly implemented :)

Comment: @andrewmu: “the main thing that people think of as HTML5 (`border-radius`) is partly implemented” Heh!

Comment: border-radius isn't HTML5, its CSS3, a completely different thing.

Comment: And border-radius isn't even HTML.  EDIT: @Psytronic - HEY!!!

Comment: @Rob You need quicker fingers than that to outtype me! :)